# Amazon S3 modify Bucket ACL

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I would like to enable permissions on bucket for log-delivery group using API for PHP 2

```
    $result = $client->putBucketAcl(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket . '-log',
        'AccessControlList' => array(
            'Grant' => array(
                'Grantee' => array(
                    'Type' => 'Group',
                    'URI' => 'http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery',
                ),
                'Permission' => 'WRITE',
            ),
            'Grant' => array(
                'Grantee' => array(
                    'Type' => 'Group',
                    'URI' => 'http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery',
                ),
                'Permission' => 'READ_ACP',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Structure of code below is written in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/LoggingHowTo.html.

Executing this code fails with exception:

```
 **Aws\S3\Exception\MissingSecurityHeaderException**

 Your request was missing a required header
```

I can`t find how to solve this exception and set ACL on bucket. Am I missing something important?

Comment: Are you providing the AWS keys in the client setup? It appears that it may not be generating the signature header on the request.

Comment: Yes I am. Because before this statement I deleted old buckets and created newone without error

Comment: I am facing the same issue while giving ACL to bucket. Have you got any solution ?